# Drop down values seen as not selected on PHP contact form?

Tags: php, forms, drop-down-menu, contacts

Just a slight problem with my drop down menus. It's probably something really simple that I've overlooked. The drop down boxes don't "see" themselves as being selected. I'm still working on the validation of the other boxes, so don't worry about them. As like all my other problems I've posted on this site, it's probably something really simple.

EDIT:
This can be fixed by adding a value to the option itself.

Comment: As you can see, the other values are seen fine as filled in, but even when a value is selected, and the submit button it pressed, it doesn't see the drop down menus as having anything in the WHEN they DO.

Comment: How are you doing your validation? Could it be that it is selecting your default select option, which is disabled, instead of the actual selected value?

Comment: The validation itself won't see the deselected option, but I now realise from Chris N's post that the value needs it own OPTION value in order for it to see the value. I always thought that having the service in the option tag itself would do the trick, turns out you need to give the option a value itself, and not just the HTML text, which make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might you need to write your option tags as

```
<option value="Roof Repairs">Roof Repairs</option>
```

Comment: Interesting. Having each different service as it's own value. I'll see how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

Try just : selected

Instead of : selected="selected"

Comment: Nope. Didn't seem to work. Even when I remove the input disabled, still have the same problem. How strange.

Comment: Try to set that : autocomplete="off" on your form.
The reason why i say that is because "Ms" isn't even the first option, it's in the middle so if you don't have anything related to the selection of these fields done in javascript i think it' just some autocompletion from your browser :)

Comment: Tried that both with the input boxes, and the form itself as well as removing the aforementioned code <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled"> but still no luck. I've taken a look at some other form PHP codes, and mine seems like it should be working fine. :/

Comment: When i copy/paste your html form into plunker it works tho...
http://plnkr.co/edit/7sMtrQAqzlBDo9hI4h1n?p=preview . What is inside your script.js file ?

Comment: Must have been a problem with my browser or something. Seems giving the value option to the option itself works. It's like telling a child to do something twice before it does it correctly. Wish I'd knew this before.

Comment: Cool you found how to fix your issue :)